# Another no endpoint listening

Tags: wcf

I read much about my problem but i can't find solution. When I go to controller with my service compiler returns:

> There was no endpoint listening at {0} that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> InnerException:
>
> Basic connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred when receiving

I try with mex and close my firewall, when I start app my service works correctly (I can visit `localhost:52093/AccountService.svc`) but when I go to controller to invoke service IIS stops working.

My `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:52093/AccountService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
        contract="AccountService.IAccountService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

E:
My Service config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Server config would be essential now, please provide :)

Comment: To the edit: There is no service, no endpoint, nothing? Are you doing that in code? We need to know how you configure the server side of your service to know the problem. Imagine someone asking: I can't plug my cable into the socket, here is my cable. Everyone will want to know what the socket looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `<service />` and `<endpoint />` tags. Refer to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to properly setup your *Web.config* for hosing your WCF service on IIS.